# Automatically export Power BI paginated report to excel

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a Power BI paginated report with a report parameter of around 150 values.
I need to run the report for each parameter and export the report into excel spreadsheet.
How do I save them automatically to my PC? Power automate is not working for some reason.
Is there a way to create data driven subscription on Power BI report server?

Comment: Try to look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-paginated-report

Comment: Hi @LevGelman, I know that link already.  I can see that there is code in .NET to export it to excel. Is there any end to end code somewhere in Python to perform the same task? Or I want to know how to pass each parameter in the subscription in the Powe BI paginated report so that I get email with excel attachment for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to set up an email subscription with Power Automate Flow.

Your first step, use the step 'export to file for paginated reports'

Then add parameters as needed (all 150 if required).

Select your file output in the first step - .xlsx, .csv, .pdf etc

Next add a new step to email the attachment with 'send an email - v2'

[image]

[image]